# B2B Azure analysis services cannot see any models

Tags: ssas, azure-active-directory, azure-analysis-services

I have created a guest invite in AAD (*xx.yy_domainX.com#EXT#@domainY.onmicrosoft.com*). Then I have added the user to Anlysis Services Admins. When I logg on from SSMS or PowerBI, I cannot find any models.

Does anyone have any ideas what have happen? Or how I can find why the error occurs?

Comment: Can you see models in Azure Portal?

Comment: I can see models with my account in domainY. But if I go into the portal with the B2B account i can't see any models because I don't have access to the service (SSAS Service) . 

Should I be able to see the service in the portal?

Comment: Have you tried granting permissions in a role to xx_yy@domainx.com (rather than the #EXT# one)?

Comment: When I didi the invite the #EXT# account was created. What is the diffence and How can I create a xx_yy@domainx.com account instead?

Comment: Hi!

That solved the porblem. I created a powershell script that generated the UserDisplayName. that fixed the probelm. Thanks!

Comment: @Liston can you elaborate or post an answer describing the solution?

Comment: Sorry for Late response. I was wrong it seems. 

I still have the same problem.

What I do is the following:
1. I create a guest invite in PowerShell 
2. I try to add this guest into a role in Azure analysis services
3. I serach for my guest the only thing I find is xx.yy_domainX.com#EXT#@domainY.onmicrosoft.com
4. I add this account
5. I try to loggin(with xx.yy@domainX.com) through SSMS or PBI but do not have a access..

Comment: I have found the answer. I needed to create a new SSAS Service in Azure. And then everything worked smoothly. 

I think that my old SSAS enviroment has not been patched correctly by Microsoft.